# Using a for loop to cycle through multiple variables?

Tags: javascript

Good evening, I am wondering if there is a way to cycle through multiple variables with a for loop? 
I have many variables set, here is my code:

```
if (MedicalIndex11 == 1) {
  if (MedicalIndex11 != MedicalIndex1) {
  temp = Medical11.value;
  Medical11.value = Medical1.value;
  Medical1.value = temp;
} else if (MedicalIndex11 != MedicalIndex3) {
  temp = Medical11.value;
  Medical11.value = Medical3.value;
  Medical3.value= temp;
} else if (MedicalIndex11 != MedicalIndex5) {
  temp = Medical11.value;
  Medical11.value = Medical5.value;
  Medical5.value = temp;
} else if (MedicalIndex11 != MedicalIndex7) {
  temp = Medical11.value;
  Medical11.value = Medical7.value;
  Medical7.value = temp;
} else if (MedicalIndex11 != MedicalIndex9) { 
  temp = Medical11.value;
  Medical11.value = Medical9.value;
  Medical9.value = temp;
} else {
}
```

EDIT:  Here is a working sample of the code with a for loop, and arrays:

```
for (i = 10; i < 30; i++) {
  if (IndexArray[i] == 1) {
    if (IndexArray[i] != MedicalIndex1) {
      temp = MedFieldArray[i].value;
      MedFieldArray[i].value = Medical1.value;
      Medical1.value = temp;
  } else if (IndexArray[i] != MedicalIndex3) { 
      temp = MedFieldArray[i].value;
      MedFieldArray[i].value = Medical3.value;
      Medical3.value= temp;
  } else if (IndexArray[i] != MedicalIndex5) {
      temp = MedFieldArray[i].value;
      MedFieldArray[i].value = Medical5.value;
      Medical5.value = temp;
  } else if (IndexArray[i] != MedicalIndex7) {
      temp = MedFieldArray[i].value;
      MedFieldArray[i].value = Medical7.value;
      Medical7.value = temp;
  } else if (IndexArray[i] != MedicalIndex9) { 
      temp = MedFieldArray[i].value;
      MedFieldArray[i].value = Medical9.value;
      Medical9.value = temp;
  } else {
 }
}
}
```

I ran the code, and the syntax seems to be fine, but it doesn't want to swap the values of the variables.  I am getting the **Medical** variables from user input from a PDF document
EDIT 2:  The Medical variables are found by user input on a PDF form, here is the code:

```
var Medical1 = this.getField("Medications 1");
var Medical3 = this.getField("Medications 3");
var Medical5 = this.getField("Medications 5");
var Medical7 = this.getField("Medications 7");
var Medical9 = this.getField("Medications 9");
var Medical11 = this.getField("Medications 11");
var Medical13 = this.getField("Medications 13");
var Medical15 = this.getField("Medications 15");
var Medical17 = this.getField("Medications 17");
var Medical19 = this.getField("Medications 19");
var Medical21 = this.getField("Medications 21");
var Medical23 = this.getField("Medications 23");
var Medical25 = this.getField("Medications 25");
var Medical27 = this.getField("Medications 27");
var Medical29 = this.getField("Medications 29");
var Medical31 = this.getField("Medications 31");
var Medical33 = this.getField("Medications 33");
var Medical35 = this.getField("Medications 35");
var Medical37 = this.getField("Medications 37");
var Medical39 = this.getField("Medications 39");
var MedicalIndex1 = 0
var MedicalIndex3 = null
var MedicalIndex5 = null
var MedicalIndex7 = null
var MedicalIndex9 = null
var MedicalIndex11 = null
var MedicalIndex13 = null
var MedicalIndex15 = null
var MedicalIndex17 = null
var MedicalIndex19 = null
var MedicalIndex21 = null
var MedicalIndex23 = null
var MedicalIndex25 = null
var MedicalIndex27 = null
var MedicalIndex29 = null
var MedicalIndex31 = null
var MedicalIndex33 = null
var MedicalIndex35 = null
var MedicalIndex37 = null
var MedicalIndex39 = null
var MedicalArray = ["DEPRESSION", "ANGINA", "BIPOLAR DEPRESSION", 
"ATHEROSCLEROSIS", "HEART ATTACK"];
 var temp = 0
```

The objective is to swap the variables that have any of the listed diagnoses from the MedicalArray, so that the first 5 **Medical** variables contain one of the several strings in the Medical Array.

Comment: Add all of them in an array and loop through array

Comment: to get a better answer, please clarify what is each of those variables. What is `MedicalIndex1` whcih kind of value it stores? `Medical1.value` is an object or a DOM node? What is the expected output?

Comment: There we go, went ahead and posted more code.  **MedicalIndex** stores either a null, or a 1, based on whether the **Medical** variable contains any of the strongs in the **MedArray*.  **Medical1** stores an object.  The objective is to have the first five **Medical** variables be, "qualifying" or contain any of the strings from the **MedArray*

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about a solution like this?

```
if (MedicalIndex11 == 1) 
{
  var i;
  for(i=1;i<=9;i+=2)
    swap(11,i);
}
else
{
}

function swap(a, b)
{
  var temp;
  if (window['MedicalIndex' + a] == window['MedicalIndex' + b]) return;
  temp = window['Medical' + a].value;
  window['Medical' + a].value = window['Medical' + b].value;
  window['Medical' + b].value = temp;
}
```